# Setting ground potential in nodal analysis matrix form

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistors, passive-networks, matrix

I have a general question concerning the matrix formulation of nodal analysis.
I investigate a large resistor network with tens of thousands of resistors and some independent current sources.

I set up the conductance matrix as usual with the positive sum of all conductances leading to a node on the main diagonal, and the negative conductances between nodes on the corresponding off-diagonal positions.

Naturally, the conductance matrix is singular as the reference potential is not chosen, i.e. I have not defined 'ground'. This leaves me with an infinite amount of solutions to the linear equation system. For very large matrices, this seems to be a problem for my software, so I'm wondering how I can easily fix one of the potentials to 0 V and maybe solve my issue.

So, I have already constructed a large sparse conductance matrix and set up the current vector. How do I fix one of the unknown voltages?

Comment: Demonstrate your problem with 3 resistors network, please...

Comment: You can even see the problem with a single resistor with a current source. You will obtain a potential on either side of the resistor, but only the voltage, i.e. the potential difference is relevant. If you use the matrix algorithm, also described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nodal_analysis#Matrix_form_for_the_node-voltage_equation) and apply it to all nodes, your point of reference is not defined.

Comment: You mustn't write a KCL equation at the reference node. This fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual approach is to simply not write a KCL equation for the ground node. Then use the fact that its potential is defined as 0 when writing equations for the other nodes. This will give a non-singular matrix if you don't do anything else goofy (put two current sources in series, for example).

An equivalent way to look at this is to eliminate the KCL equation for the ground node, and add an equation 
$$V_{\rm gnd}=0.$$

In the first case for a network of N nodes you have N-1 equations and N-1 unknowns. In the second case you have N equations and N unknowns (but one of the unknowns is trivial to find).

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I think, the second option is probably easier to implement. I could simply skip the off-diagonal elements in the respective column/row. 
I falsely assumed that if I did so, I would neglect the conductances leading to this node but they are obviously contained in the diagonal elements of the neighboring nodes.